# Limit if data in Google Apps Script connected with Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any limit of data between Google Sheet and Google Script?

I know about quotas of apps script, my question is if a limit of the number of rows exists when you edit a big google sheet from Google apps script.

My problem is:

I take like 1000 rows x 30 cols from Google Sheet with SpreadsheetApp and i put that in an Array is Google Apps script, then I make some conditionals in Javascript to detect some stuff, and then I edit that sheet (with 1000 rows x 30 cols) with google apps script and SpreadsheetApp. My script works well many months with data like 200 rows x 30 columns but now with x5 data my script is failing. The script is not reporting an error, it just make the edition really wrong. It would be possible the amount of data?

Comment: How is it doing it "really wrong"? Not adding all the data? Wrong computations? Maybe something else?

Comment: Editing wrong cells. For some reason the script choosing wrong cells. Weird thing because it works well with few data...

Comment: This could be a known limitation, a programming bug on your part, or a Sheets/Apps Script bug. For what I'm understanding you are loading an entire sheet, modifying its values and setting all the values again. Is that right? Also, how are you doing that? What methods do you call? Could you add some kind of pseudo script or simplified version for us to know?

Comment: I get the entire Sheet in Array (google apps script)
I make some conditionals (Like If then else) to detect something to edit
When i detect something to edit, i go to the sheet and edit that cell

I mean, i edit cell by cell. I dont paste the entire sheet again.

Is the typically CRUD evaluation. I get the array, evaluate conditions, and go to sheet to edit what is necessary.

Comment: 1. Call Sheet
2. Get all sheet in Array in Apps Script
3. Make a lot of FOR and IF to analyze that Array
4. When i need to edit, i go to the sheet directly and edit that cell
5. End

Comment: I dont edit the array in the entire process

Comment: I'm assuming that nobody can edit the spreadsheet while the script is running, right? Also it's hard to tell what is going on, as I'm not even sure the nature of your data or if your code is correct. Could you try to reproduce it on a smaller scale? Or at least some way of looking into it? (note that this forum is public, do not post sensitive information here)

Comment: Imagine a tyipcally Sheet with transactions of Sales. You have in each row a transaction and the colums are the Header information for each one.  I think exists a limit for SpreadsheetApp or GAS when you reach a "big" sheet like that

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this happen, but I can't ensure that this isn't a bug. If you have a Workspace account you can [contact Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) and ask them to take a look into it.